# Register custom DVC plugin to FreeRDP client

Tags: rdp, freerdp

I want to port a DVC (dynamic virtual channel) plugin from standard Microsoft RDP to FreeRDP for multiplatform use. But I have run into a brick wall regarding connecting the plugin into the FreeRDP client. While for Microsoft RDP on Windows you use Windows Registry for this, the documentation is quite lacking regarding usage of custom DVC on FreeRDP. Command-line interface has `/dvc` and `/a` for connecting plugins, and there's a `drdynvc` plugin which could possibly be used for this, but I am having a hard time reverse-engineering the code to learn how to use it (again, documentation is lacking info on `drdynvc`).
I would appreciate any information on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any future FreeRDP DVC enthusiasts:
To attach a plugin, you have to use `/dvc:<name>` cli option, with the name of the plugin, and move the desired plugin lib to folders:
On Windows 7+ it looks in a static path `C:\Program Files (x86)\FreeRDP\lib\freerdp2\<name>-client.dll`
On MacOS: `<FreeRDP install path>/lib/freerdp2/lib<name>-client.dylib`
         if it's build from source then `/usr/local/lib/freerdp2/lib<name>-client.dylib`

If unsure, you can check the cmake-generated file `build-config.h` in `\include\freerdp\`.